# CSS Как поставить элемент по центру экрана, что б не влияли на другие элементы?

Tags: css, css3, центрирование

Есть вот такой упрощенный пример

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body:before{
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00f;
  z-index: 10;
}
body:after{
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #00f;
  z-index: 10;
}

.block_img {
  align-self: center;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #0f0;
}

.testment {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 4;
}

.block {
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_img"></div>
<div class="testment">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, at minima laudantium illo! Nobis minus non sit, voluptate natus id.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem unde recusandae assumenda debitis et vel iure provident voluptatum, dolorum sint ullam iste sequi. Qui aliquid ipsa reprehenderit cumque, sapiente, dolorum tempore iste tenetur commodi
    distinctio vero. Consectetur quis odit veritatis!</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae maiores voluptates soluta quam, nam quibusdam!</div>
</div>
```

Страница с контентом ограничена по размерам областью видимости экрана устройства.

Вопрос - Как задать CSS что б салатовый блок, всегда был по центру экрана (Через `position:absolute`, `position:fixed` не предлагать) а его размещение не влеяло на нижний блок со списком?

[image: центрирование элементов]

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так получилось через grid

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body:before{
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00f;
  z-index: 10;
}
body:after{
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #00f;
  z-index: 10;
}

.block_img {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #0f0;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.testment {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.block {
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="block_img"></div>
<div class="testment">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero, at minima laudantium illo! Nobis minus non sit, voluptate natus id.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem unde recusandae assumenda debitis et vel iure provident voluptatum, dolorum sint ullam iste sequi. Qui aliquid ipsa reprehenderit cumque, sapiente, dolorum tempore iste tenetur commodi
    distinctio vero. Consectetur quis odit veritatis!</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae maiores voluptates soluta quam, nam quibusdam!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не внимательно читаете условие -   `position:absolute, position:fixed` не использовать, ведь не зря написано было. Идея в том, что б данный салатовый блок не выпадал из потока построения.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в каком месте вы увидели position? before и after это вы сами начертили крестик, что бы мы видели где должен быть зелёный квадрат. Удалите before и after и всё.

Comment: Вы сами свой css не понимаете?

Comment: Прошу, прощения, был не прав. Посмотрел на результат, что выводит браузер, увидел, что салатовый прямоугольник залазит поверх объектов `.testment`, сразу подумал про `position:fixed` в код не вчитивался, вот и написал. В любом случаиии это пока не тот результат которій ищу. Необходимо что б объекты не налазили один на другой.